# Robotframework - "failed: ImportError: No module named requests"

Tags: python, robotframework

I got "No module named requests" error while this module is installed (more details after the error):

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/Users/adikeller/Applications/GIT/BeAm/Beacon_4.10/STABILITY/beacon_stability_random_beacon_types.txt': Importing test library 'BeAm.beacon.tests.BeaconTesting' failed: ImportError: No module named requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adikeller/Applications/GIT/BeAm/BeAm/beacon/tests.py", line 5, in <module>
    from BeAm.beacon.counters import BeaconCounter
  File "/Users/adikeller/Applications/GIT/BeAm/BeAm/beacon/counters.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
PYTHONPATH:
  /Users/adikeller/vevn/bin
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
  /Users/adikeller/Applications/GIT/BeAm
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

Things I already done:

1. Add working directory to PYTHONPATH:
   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/adikeller/Applications/GIT/BeAm
2. Installed "requests" module:
   sudo pip install requests
3. pip freeze:
   ...
   request==0.0.22
   requests==2.18.3
   robot==20071211
   robotframework==3.0.2
   robotframework-databaselibrary==0.8.1
   robotframework-DiffLibrary2==0.0.2.dev0
   robotframework-httplibrary==0.4.2
   robotframework-pycurllibrary==0.9.5
   robotframework-rammbock==0.4.0.1
   robotframework-requests==0.4.5
   robotframework-ride==1.5.2.1
   robotframework-selenium2library==1.7.4
   robotframework-sshlibrary==2.1.2
   ...

Additional info:

1. I use MacBook macOS Sierra (V.10.12.6)
2. I run in virtualenv and I'm in it, all modules are installed there.
3. I located in the running folder:
   /Users/adikeller/Applications/GIT/BeAm
4. Running command line:
   pybot Beacon_4.10/STABILITY/beacon_stability_random_beacon_types.txt

beacon_stability_random_beacon_types.txt :

```
*** Settings ***
Force Tags        Critical    template    Conf=3    isTor=0    isSanity=0    headless    rcmd
Library           BeAm.beacon.tests.BeaconTesting    WITH NAME    BeaconTesting
Library           Collections
Library           BeAm.beacon.stability_and_stress_tests
Library           BeAm.beacon.tests
Resource          ../../BeAm/beacon/settings.txt

*** Test Cases ***
Create Test Object
    [Tags]    must
    ${TEST} =    BeaconTesting.Get Beacon Test    3
    Set Suite Variable    ${TEST}    ${TEST}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to install request library first then retry

```
$ sudo pip install requests
```

Comment: Thanks, I already try that (as describe in point #2 above), it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Fo some reason the module counters.py did not find "requests":
```File "/Users/adikeller/Applications/GIT/BeAm/BeAm/beacon/counters.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests```

Check the code for modifications on PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Hi,
I notice it works only when I add "--pythonpath /Users/adikeller/Applications/GIT/BeAm" to the running command line, it means robotframework don't refer to PYTHONPATH parameter (where it already include this path).
Any suggestance why robotframework doesn't refer to PYTHONPATH?